# Use the typescript tokenizer without the other completion providers and code hints

Tags: monaco-editor

I would like to use Monaco to edit ES6 code and would like syntax coloring. Monarch provides a basic JavaScript tokenizer at https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html, but it isn't ES6 compliant. The typescript languages tokenizer is ES6 compliment, but when it comes with a lot of extra features I don't want, like code completion and type hints.

Is it possible to use only the typescript tokenizer, or is there a monarch tokenizer for ES6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use monaco editor for syntax highlighting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52700307/how-to-use-monaco-editor-for-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 0):

When passing options to an editor instance, you can disable most providers:

```
const options = {
  value: 'var c=1;',
  hover: false, 
  quickSuggestions: false,
  wordBasedSuggestions: false
};
monaco.editor.create(DOMElement, options);
```

All possible options are detailed [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#interfaces/editor.IEditorConstructionOptions.html).

Comment: This link https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditoroptions.html doesn't seem to be active any more.