# How to use monaco editor for syntax highlighting?

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, monaco-editor

I developing a code based chat component. Every chat is some code snippet. For user input, I am using [monaco-editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor). It works fine.

But as soon as user hits send button, I get raw input from Monaco editor. I need to append this user input to chat list and again highlight this input.

Is there a way I can use Monaco editor to do this? Or do I have to use [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) along with Monaco?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had the same problem so I created issue #1171:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1171

and two solutions were provided:

a) Format an existing HTML element:

```
monaco.editor.colorizeElement(document.getElementById("yourElement"));
```

Here is a playground link for trying this out live: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#creating-the-editor-syntax-highlighting-for-html-elements

b) Format a text which is not part of any element. This is a more generic approach which returns a Promise:

```
const code = "source code";
monaco.editor.colorize(code, "javascript")
  .then(html => document.getElementById("yourElement").innerHTML = html);
```

Documentation:

- https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.editor.html#colorize

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is still searching, there's currently a declarative syntax highlighter for Monaco Editor, called [Monarch](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html)

Answer (score 3):

**Monarch minimal example**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750400/895245 mentioned monarch, and an official minimal example can be found at https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/blob/6d7b03a1de53f34272e65b7b23dbf4c5dd1c575b/browser-amd-monarch/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>

<h2>Monarch Tokenizer Sample</h2>
<div id="container" style="width:800px;height:600px;border:1px solid grey"></div>

<script src="../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
<script>
    require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' }});

    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {

        monaco.languages.register({
            id: 'myCustomLanguage'
        });
        monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('myCustomLanguage', {
            tokenizer: {
                root: [
                    [/\[error.*/, "custom-error"],
                    [/\[notice.*/, "custom-notice"],
                    [/\[info.*/, "custom-info"],
                    [/\[[a-zA-Z 0-9:]+\]/, "custom-date"],
                ],
            }
        });

        // Define a new theme that constains only rules that match this language
        monaco.editor.defineTheme('myCoolTheme', {
            base: 'vs',
            inherit: false,
            rules: [
                { token: 'custom-info', foreground: '808080' },
                { token: 'custom-error', foreground: 'ff0000', fontStyle: 'bold' },
                { token: 'custom-notice', foreground: 'FFA500' },
                { token: 'custom-date', foreground: '008800' },
            ]
        });
        
        var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
            theme: 'myCoolTheme',
            value: getCode(),
            language: 'myCustomLanguage'
        });
    });

    function getCode() {
        return [
            '[Sun Mar 7 16:02:00 2004] [notice] Apache/1.3.29 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations',
            '[Sun Mar 7 16:02:00 2004] [info] Server built: Feb 27 2004 13:56:37',
            '[Sun Mar 7 16:02:00 2004] [notice] Accept mutex: sysvsem (Default: sysvsem)',
            '[Sun Mar 7 16:05:49 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 16:45:56 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:13:50 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:21:44 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:23:53 2004] statistics: Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /home/httpd/twiki/lib/TWiki.pm line 528.',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:23:53 2004] statistics: Can\'t create file /home/httpd/twiki/data/Main/WebStatistics.txt - Permission denied',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:27:37 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:31:39 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 17:58:00 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 18:00:09 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 18:10:09 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 18:19:01 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 18:42:29 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 18:52:30 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 18:58:52 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 19:03:58 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 19:08:55 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 20:04:35 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 20:11:33 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 20:12:55 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 20:25:31 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 20:44:48 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 20:58:27 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 21:16:17 2004] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /home/httpd/twiki/view/Main/WebHome',
            '[Sun Mar 7 21:20:14 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 21:31:12 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 21:39:55 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Sun Mar 7 21:44:10 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 01:35:13 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 01:47:06 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 01:59:13 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 02:12:24 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 02:54:54 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 03:46:27 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 03:48:18 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 03:52:17 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 03:55:09 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 04:22:55 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 04:24:47 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 04:40:32 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 04:55:40 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 04:59:13 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 05:22:57 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 05:24:29 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '[Mon Mar 8 05:31:47 2004] [info] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] (104)Connection reset by peer: client stopped connection before send body completed',
            '<11>httpd[31628]: [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /usr/local/installed/apache/htdocs/squirrelmail/_vti_inf.html in 29-Mar 15:18:20.50 from xx.xx.xx.xx',
            '<11>httpd[25859]: [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /usr/local/installed/apache/htdocs/squirrelmail/_vti_bin/shtml.exe/_vti_rpc in 29-Mar 15:18:20.54 from xx.xx.xx.xx',
        ].join('\n');;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

For a standalone version without cloning that repo you can base yourself on: [How to run the Monaco editor from a CDN like cdnjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63179813/how-to-run-the-monaco-editor-from-a-cdn-like-cdnjs)